# bootstrap hide on small screens not working?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I don't know if the problem is because my browser, It is supposed to be working, simply I want the first pills-tab to be hidden on small screens and visible on medium and larger screens, and the second pills-tab to be visible on small screens and hidden on large screens and larger.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-2 d-sm-none d-md-block">
    <div class="nav flex-column list-group" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="v-pills-all-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-all" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-all" aria-selected="true">small no</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-paid-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-paid" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-paid" aria-selected="false">Paid</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-free-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-free" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-free" aria-selected="false">Free</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-pending-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pending" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pending" aria-selected="false">Pending</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 d-sm-block d-md-none">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-all-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-all" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-all" aria-selected="true">All</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-paid-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-paid" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-paid" aria-selected="false">Paid</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-free-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-free" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-free" aria-selected="false">Free</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-pending-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pending" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pending" aria-selected="false">Pending</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use "d-none, d-md-none, d-sm-none etc..." class to hide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way these utility classes of Bootstrap work, is that they apply a style to the specified width and up. So with applying `d-sm-none`, you are assigning the style `display:none` to the element from sm-width and up. To apply this style from the smallest breakpoint and up, you should use `d-none`.

So change your `<div class=”col-2 d-sm-none d-md-block”>` to `<div class=”col-2 d-none d-md-block”>`.

In addition you could remove the `d-sm-block` from your second div, as `display:block` is already applied by the `col-*` classes.

Besides, to me it seems like you want to show the same menu with different styles applied to it, depending on the screen size. Correct me if I'm wrong.

For this situation I would recommend to have only one html block for the menu and applying styles according to the size of the screen, instead of duplicating the content.

See this fiddle as an approximation: https://jsfiddle.net/p8ek5ths/

Comment: The OP uses a small navigation from `md` and up. So for your fiddle i would add `col-dm-2` to `<div class="col-12">`.

Comment: thank you Artur, how can I place the menu in the center of the width, mean margin: 0 auto; on small screens only?

Comment: You could either use `mx-auto` as class on the col, or use a div with the classes `row justify-content-center` around the navigation.

Comment: Yes, @ThomasScheffer said your best and cleanest possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Add This Class `d-none` for `<div class="col-2 d-sm-none d-md-block">`

```
<div class="col-2 d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="nav flex-column list-group" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action active" id="v-pills-all-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-all" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-all" aria-selected="true">small no</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-paid-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-paid" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-paid" aria-selected="false">Paid</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-free-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-free" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-free" aria-selected="false">Free</a>
      <a class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" id="v-pills-pending-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pending" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pending" aria-selected="false">Pending</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 d-sm-block d-md-none">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-all-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-all" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-all" aria-selected="true">All</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-paid-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-paid" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-paid" aria-selected="false">Paid</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-free-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-free" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-free" aria-selected="false">Free</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " id="v-pills-pending-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-pending" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-pending" aria-selected="false">Pending</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/wp57bsgk/2/